# Show all failing builds in TFS/VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've created a widget for TFS/VSTS which allows you to see the number of failing builds. This number is based on the last builds result for each build definition. I've read the REST api documentation, but the only way to get this result is:

1. [Get the list of definitions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-list-of-build-definitions)
2. [Get the list of builds filtered by;definition=[allIds], maxBuildsPerDefinition = 1, resultFilter=failed](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-a-list-of-builds)

This is actually pretty slow (2x callback, lot's of response data) and I thought it should be possible in a single query. One of the problems is that the maxBuildsPerDefinition doesn't work without the definition filter. Does anyone have an idea how to load this data more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is no. The way you use is the most efficient way for now.